# Joomla: What is a good technical approach for data entry?

Tags: php, joomla

I have a background in .NET and Perl, but have found myself working on a project where the customer is mandating Joomla. They would like me to setup a web site that will allow them to enter rental properties, which would likely include a large description field and a number of smaller metadata fields. What is a good way to approach this problem using Joomla? Would I somehow add metadata fields to articles for entry of rental properties? Would I need to create something outside the realm of an article (I'm thinking maybe a component, based on some intro training videos that I have watched on Joomla)?

My HTML and CSS skills are pretty solid, and I have a little bit of experience with PHP, so I don't mind getting my hands dirty. However, I'd like to get an idea of how a Joomla veteran would approach the problem.

Comment: You probably need to check if there is any export/import articles modules , that would help?
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/migration-a-conversion/data-import-a-export

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to tack meta information on to the articles is almost certainly not the way to go - for a ton of reasons. You are on the right track with a component. Consider designing a component with a back-end database, admin capability and a few front-end data-entry/information screens. The Joomla framework is a little cumbersome to begin with, but ultimately the MVC implementation makes sense and is quite powerful.

[This tutorial at the Joomla documentation wiki](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Introduction) runs through pretty much everything you need to know from a basic "hello world" to databases and more complex implementations. It sounds like the basic database-enabled example would get you really close to your objective. The example application builds on itself from one tutorial to the next, so it is not at all a waste to start at the beginning and work through it.

And a couple random bits of advice for a Joomla component development beginner:

One thing you may want to research related to data-entry is the JHTML class (the JHTML::_() function in particular). IMO the approach is less than intuitive, but using it is required to leverage built-in widget classes defined for [the standard form fields](http://docs.joomla.org/Form_field#Standard_form_field_types) in more advanced applications. It is also important for working with customized form field types and handlers.

Also, the objects returned by JFactory::getApplication() and JFactory::getDocument() have a ton of useful/important functionality when it comes to manipulating the Joomla application (like access to the JInput object). Get familiar with what they can do and remember how to retrieve them.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

While building a component from scratch is the most flexible the initial learning curve might be too expensive (time wise) if you're not experienced with PHP and the Joomla framework.

Generally, if we're asked to do something outside our normal areas in Joomla the first place I look is the [Joomla Extension Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) (JED).

From that I can usually find a very good solution or a very near match. If it's not a perfect match I can easily extend it (e.g. adding a plugin for a local payment gateway) or work with the developer to add the features we need to the extensions core). Which is probably a good way to start with Joomla, i.e. modifying or extending an existing extension.

You're lucky though, the area you're interested in has it's own category on the JED — the [Real Estate section](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/vertical-markets/real-estate) has 15 items listed and most them seem to have good ratings and reviews.

So, I'd start there.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a form plugin for articles to add the extra field or to divide the body field into sections with json or using the profile plugin as a model you could add fields and store them in a separate table.

YOu could repurpose the contact component and use its many fields, or just clone it and change the names.

You could also use an advanced form extension.